# question about Graphviz

Tags: graphics, graphviz

due to the size of graph, Grapgviz sometimes exceeds its memory

so I want to ask

except Grapgviz, if there any software can be used to plot my large graph

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot.

I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard about [Gephi](http://gephi.org/), it doesn't support the DOT file format yet though.

[Supported Graph Formats | Gephi](http://gephi.org/support/supported-graph-formats/)